# How to enable the autoplay feature for a video on html?

Tags: javascript, html, video, embed, autoplay

I want to embed a video from a streaming website but not from famous sites like youtube or vimeo.

How can I enable the autoplay feature? I've found the answer for youtube videos but what about other streaming sites? Is there a general solution for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A video that will automatically start playing if you have a direct link:

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know that code and I've used this code and other similar codes. But this is for when we upload the video to our own host. But I want to embed a video from a streaming site.
I paste the video link as src but doesn't work. Because those links redirect to the whole page. You know what I mean? the page with similar clips, comment section and stuff. 
Another link is needed. like a direct link to the video or... I don't know :-?

Comment: @ata Can you give a link to the video?

Comment: This is the link to the page:
https://www.aparat.com/v/3o6WU/

and this is the embedding code it gives us:
<div id="69080589590"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/3o6WU?data[rnddiv]=69080589590&data[responsive]=yes"></script></div>

Comment: Try to ask their tech support for autoplay params like YouTube or Vimeo have